How to test if GDAL works with NetCDF
I just installed the latest GDAL version today and wanted to transform a GeoTIFF file into NetCDF file. The version of my GDAL and NetCDF is listed below.
$ gdalwarp --version
GDAL 3.9.3, released 2024/10/07 (debug build)

$ ncdump -version
......
netcdf library version 4.9.2 of Oct 28 2024 21:15:49 $

However, whenever I wanted to do something with NetCDF, segmentation fault occurred. For example, I use gdalwarp as below:
$ gdalwarp -overwrite -t_srs "+proj=stere \
    +lat_0=90.0 +lon_0=-98.0 +lat_ts=45.0 \
    +R=6370000.0" -te -10746000.0 -10746000.0 \
    10746000.0 10746000.0 -tr 108000.0 108000.0 \
    -r average -wo NUM_THREADS=6 -of netcdf \
    SMAP_L4_SM_gph_20190301T013000_Vv7032_001_Geophysical_Data.tif test
Creating output file that is 199P x 199L.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

This is really confusing. After that, I just wanted to see if gdalinfo works fine, but it turned out to be that if gdalinfo were to read a NetCDF file, the segmentation fault occurred as well.
What is the method to test if GDAL works with NetCDF?
==========UPDATE==========
I think the issue might be related to the interface between NetCDF and GDAL, so I ran the command below and got those outputs
$ strings libgdal.so.35.3.9.3 | grep -i netcdf | grep error
netcdf error #%d : %s .
A general error occurred when writing a netCDF dataset
netcdf error #%d : %s .
An error occurred while writing metadata to the netCDF file.
An error occurred while attempting to write a feature to the target netCDF file.
A general error occurred when writing a netCDF dataset
netcdf error #%d : %s .
An error occurred while writing the target netCDF File. Translation will be terminated.
A general error occurred when writing a netCDF dataset
netcdf error #%d : %s .
netcdf error #%d : %s .
netcdf error #%d : %s .
netcdf error #%d : %s .

Those outputs are ambiguous, so I ran
strings libgdal.so.35.3.9.3 | grep -i -C 5 'netcdf.*error'

to find out more. Among them there is two suspicious information saying that
Unsupported GDAL datatype %s, treat as NC_DOUBLE.
UInt64
Unsupported GDAL datatype (%d), treat as NC_FLOAT.
Band%d
/public/home/huangty/gdal-3.9.3/frmts/netcdf/netcdfdataset.cpp
netcdf error #%d : %s .
at (%s,%s,%d)
netCDFRasterBand
nc_def_var(%d,%s,%d) id=%d
GDAL Band Number %d
adding valid_range attributes for Byte Band
--
A partially supported measured feature type was detected. X, Y, Z Geometry will be preserved but the measure axis and related information will be removed.
Translation of a simple geometry layer has been terminated prematurely due to an error.
SRS settings
interior_ring
/public/home/huangty/gdal-3.9.3/frmts/netcdf/netcdflayersg.cpp
netcdf error #%d : %s .
at (%s,%s,%d)
SGCommitPendingTransaction
attribute:
part_node_count
An error occurred while writing the target netCDF File. Translation will be terminated.
--

Could this indicate something to my problem?

gdalinfo --formats will tell you which formats are supported - it seems that you have a library mismatch if gdalinfo crashes

The netCDF is supported as gdalinfo --formats puts it. Could you please tell me how to find out that mismatch library? Thank you for your help!

Well, I have managed to find out what's going on. The reason is that my libnetcdf.so.19 and libgdal.so.35.3.9.3 are using different interpreter and different rpath. That's because even though you can set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH when you compile netCDF, but you need to do more, or your netCDF still uses /lib64 as its rpath. To fix this, I re-compiled netCDF and my instructions are as follows:
cmake .. -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/tools/NetCDF \
-D BUILD_UTILITIES=ON \
-D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=true -Wno-dev \
-D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=$HOME/tools/GCC/11.5.0/bin/gcc  \
-D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=$HOME/tools/GCC/11.5.0/bin/c++  \
-D CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$HOME/lib:$HOME/tools/hdf5/lib:$HOME/tools/zlib/lib  \
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH=$HOME/lib  \
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=$HOME/lib  \
-D prefix_result:INTERNAL=$HOME/lib  \
-D HAVE_LIBM:FILEPATH=$HOME/lib/libm.so  \
-D HDF5_C_LIBRARY_dl:FILEPATH=$HOME/lib/libdl.so  \
-D HDF5_C_LIBRARY_m:FILEPATH=$HOME/lib/libm.so  \
-D HDF5_C_LIBRARY_sz:FILEPATH=$HOME/lib/libsz.so  \
-D HDF5_C_LIBRARY_z:FILEPATH=$HOME/lib/libz.so

Perhaps you do not need to set all of them, or maybe you need to set even more, you can find out your own settings by check your CMakeCache.txt, for example:
grep -i /lib64 /path/to/gdal/build/CMakeCache.txt
grep -i /usr/lib /path/to/gdal/build/CMakeCache.txt

and manually set those offtrack flags to your desired path. And after installation, you may need to use tools like patchelf, chrpath etc. to make them work without segmentation fault.
I think it might be helpful to someone who has updated GLIBC but have not put them into /lib64 like me.

If you are on linux (and I suspect you are from your prompt), you can do ldd /usr/bin/gdalinfo to see which shared libraries it is linked against.
On my system (Ubuntu 22.04) I get:
$: gdalinfo --version
   GDAL 3.4.1, released 2021/12/27
$: ldd /usr/bin/gdalinfo | grep cdf
   libnetcdf.so.19 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdf.so.19 (0x0000708180451000)


Thanks for your reply and sorry for my delay. I fintd it strange that both ldd and gdalinfo --formats (as you mentioned above) work well:
$ gdalinfo --formats | grep -i cdf   netCDF -raster,multidimensional raster,vector- (rw+s): Network Common Data Format (*.nc)
$  ldd ~/tools/GDAL/3.9.3/bin/gdalwarp | grep cdf         libnetcdf.so.19 => /public/home/huangty/lib/libnetcdf.so.19 (0x00002b2f1c46c000)
However, I still got same segmentation error when netCDF files involved.

I've gone through some inspection on libgdal.so.35.3.9.3, please see those updates in my question above.

I use OSGeo4W and I have
GDAL 3.10.0dev-b6edb5191e, released 2024/10/07
NETCDF_VERSION=4.9.2 of Jun 28 2024 14:43:26

I made a set of tests from simple to more complex, with no problem.
gdalwarp -of netcdf  test.tif test.nc
Creating output file that is 12000P x 12000L.
Processing test.tif [1/1] : 0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.

gdalwarp -of netcdf  -t_srs "+proj=stere +lat_0=90.0 +lon_0=-98.0 +lat_ts=45.0 +R=6370000.0" test.tif test2.nc
Creating output file that is 16714P x 16710L.
Processing test.tif [1/1] : 0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.

gdalwarp -of netcdf  -t_srs "+proj=stere +lat_0=90.0 +lon_0=-98.0 +lat_ts=45.0 +R=6370000.0" -tr 108000.0 108000.0 test.tif test3.nc
Creating output file that is 1P x 1L.
Processing test.tif [1/1] : 0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.

gdalwarp -of netcdf  -t_srs "+proj=stere +lat_0=90.0 +lon_0=-98.0 +lat_ts=45.0 +R=6370000.0" -tr 108000.0 108000.0 -te -10746000.0 -10746000.0 10746000.0 10746000.0  test.tif test4.nc
Creating output file that is 199P x 199L.
Processing test.tif [1/1] : 0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.

Either you have problem with your GDAL installation or there is something special in "SMAP_L4_SM_gph_20190301T013000_Vv7032_001_Geophysical_Data.tif". Can gdalinfo read it? Can you convert it into another TIFF with gdal_translate?

Yes, both gdalinfo and gdaltranslate work fine with this TIFF. The segmentation fault happens only when netCDF is involved, for example using gdalinfo to read a netCDF file, or convert this file into netCDF format. I may consider there is something wrong with the connection between gdal and netCDF, but I don't know the way to find out. Could you please tell me how? Thanks a lot!
